# HC-05(ZS-040) not responding to AT+INIT

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm using HC-05 Bluetooth module(ZS-040) right now.  the module goes into command mode and respond to only few commands like, AT,AT+ROLE?,AT+ADDR?
But as soon as I use AT+INIT it comes out of command mode and light starts to blink faster. Can you kindly help me out?
I have even tried replacing the module in case that is not working but still the problem remains.

**The code I'm using is given below-**

[code for HC-05 to enter command mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFxzp.png)

Comment: The code is running fine for older version of HC-05 i.e. not ZS-040 model and that is responding to all commands.
This new ZS-040 model is not responding to AT+INIT

Comment: That happened to me, but connecting the pin "EN" or key or pin 34 like in other places call him to 3.3v or to any other configured as OUTPUT and HIGH. now INIT return me ok, but AT+INQ is making me the same, or sometimes return OK and nothing else.

Comment: KEY must be high (or button pressed if your adapter board has one) while you type the command.

Comment: And faster blinking doesn't mean leaving AT command mode.